# ESLint simple-import-sort

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, sorting, eslint

I am trying to use the `eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort` library to sort my imports. I am trying to get my imports to look like this:

```
... some imports

... some another imports

import EllipsisTableCell from 'components/common/tables/Table/ColoredTableCell.styled';
import StripedDataTable from '../../common/tables/Table/StripedDataTable.styled';
import StripedDataCell from './StripedDataCell.styled'
import { CustomTableHeader } from './styles';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
```

My `.eslintrc.json` file looks like this (omitted for clarity):

```
"plugins": ["react", "simple-import-sort"]


"overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["*.js", "*.jsx", "*.ts", "*.tsx"], 
    "rules": {
      "simple-import-sort/imports": [
        "error",
        {
          "groups": [
            ["^react", "^@?\\w"],
            ["^components|^graphql|^helpers|^hooks|^theme|^config|^models|^state|^types?\\w"],
            ["^\\u0000", "^\\.", "^", "^\\./(?=.*/)(?!/?$)", "^\\.(?!/?$)", "^\\./?$"],
            ["^.+\\.?(styled)$", "^.+\\.?(styles)$", "^.+\\.?(css)$"],
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I can't group styled component with absolute path with another styled components

In results I have:

```
import EllipsisTableCell from 'components/common/tables/Table/ColoredTableCell.styled';

import StripedDataTable from '../../common/tables/Table/StripedDataTable.styled';
import StripedDataCell from './StripedDataCell.styled'
import { CustomTableHeader } from './styles';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';
```